# Stop moving object from going out of screen in android

Tags: android

i am moving a  object via onTouch in android, but the object goes out of the screen , how can i stop it ?

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        DisplayMetrics dm = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        final int parentHeight = dm.heightPixels;
        final int parentWidth = dm.widthPixels;

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) this
                .getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.leftMargin = Math.min(Math.max(0, (x - m_X)),
                parentWidth - this.getWidth());
        layoutParams.topMargin = Math.min(Math.max(0, (y - m_Y)),
                parentHeight - this.getHeight());
        layoutParams.rightMargin = Math.min(Math.max(0, (x - m_W)),
                parentWidth - this.getWidth());
        layoutParams.bottomMargin = Math.min(Math.max(0, (y - m_Z)),
                parentHeight + this.getHeight());
        this.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

contructors are :

```
public FTFLImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public FTFLImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    private void init() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                150, 150);
        this.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        this.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

    }
```

and the class begins as :

```
public class FTFLImageView extends ImageView implements OnTouchListener{
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use basic math.

The maximum left margin is the parent's container width minus the width of the view you are moving - and of course larger than zero.

The maximum top margin is the parent's container height minus the height of the view you are moving - and of course larger than zero.

Here's an example, I'm using the whole screen size as the parent container's dimension, adapt it to fit your needs.

```
// using display size here, it's better to use the parent container's dimensions!
DisplayMetrics dm = getResources().getDisplayMetrics(); 

final int parentHeight = dm.heightPixels;
final int parentWidth  = dm.widthPixels;

...

case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)v.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.leftMargin = Math.min(Math.max(0, (x - m_X)), parentWidth-v.getWidth());
            layoutParams.topMargin = Math.min(Math.max(0, (y - m_Y)), parentHeight-v.getHeight())
            v.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            Toast.makeText(context,"X="+x+"Y="+y, 5000).show();
            break;
```

Comment: what should be in getResources() method ?

Comment: Every View in Android has the `getResources()` method by default.... Is your code inside a View class?

Comment: please extend the code by editing your question. Your class already has a `getResources()` method since it's a view.

Comment: left and top margin is working now but what about the right and bottom ?

Comment: i have changed the move option above

Comment: to position a view you only need left and top margin since this fixes the coordinates in a 2D system. Just set right/bottom margin to zero.

Comment: the margin is ok now , but if i move the image object to right or bottom the image get shrinked